# iPhone user's mobile number

Tags: iphone

Can I get user's mobile number (CLI number) in Objective-C on the iPhone from its sim card?

Comment: Isn't this a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os ?

Comment: interesting read: http://www.kuberan.me/2011/03/your-mobile-numbers-are-being-stolen-by-websites/

Answer (score 5):

Not with the official SDK. You could ask the user to point to its own contact entry using the AddressBookUI framework's pickers, or a UI of your own design.

Comment: In fact, ICE (one of the apps in the store) does exactly this - it asks the user to pick themselves out of the contacts.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the user's phone # from NSUserDefaults. And then look up their address book entry.

This method is completely undocumented and liable to break at a moments noticed.

Also it is fragile - user might have a bad address book with the same # used multiple times etc.