# Unique identifier for an iPhone app

Tags: ios

For an iPhone app that submits images to a server I need somehow to tie all the images from a particular phone together.  With every submit I'd like to send some unique phone id.  Looked at

```
  [[UIDevice mainDevice] uniqueIdentifier]

and
  [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] stringForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"]
```

but getting errors in the simulator.

Is there an Apple sanctioned way of doing this?

Comment: Can you access the serial number?

Comment: was getting an error with <pre>[[UIDevice mainDevice] uniqueIdentifier]</pre>  but 
<pre> [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]</pre>
seems to work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os for why getting SBFormattedPhoneNumber no longer works.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What errors are you getting? `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` (*edited to fix API, thanks Martin!*) is the officially recommended way of doing this.

Comment: *** +[UIDevice mainDevice]: unrecognized:

however tried [UIDevice currentDevice] and it works in the sim

Comment: `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` is now deprecated as of iOS 5.0 - don't use it.  I've read that this GitHub repo is producing a unique ID with an open source library: https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5

Answer (score 18):

You can also use CFUUID to generate a UUID. Here's some code:

```
NSString *uuid = nil;
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
if (theUUID) {
  uuid = NSMakeCollectable(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID));
  [uuid autorelease];
  CFRelease(theUUID);
}
```

Comment: No, different every time, so usually you'd generate it on first launch and then save it to your preferences using NSUserDefaults.

Comment: The downside to this is that if the app is deleted and reinstalled or if the device is restored from backup, you'll lose the saved UUID and things won't be recognized as from the same device.

Comment: I had to type theUUID as CFUUIDRef, not CFUUID.

And don't forget to add CoreFoundation to your project, and import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

Answer (score 13):

By far the easiest and most appropriate way to obtain a unique identifier is to use the mechanisms Apple explicitly provides for obtaining one - `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]`.  You can not guarantee that the phone number will be unique to the device or that the device will even have a phone number. Beyond that, doing so is a horrible idea as it is a definite invasion of the user's privacy. Even the `uniqueidentifier` should be hashed if you are going to store it in any way.

Comment: +1 for calling out the privacy concerns. So many just ignore this aspect.

Comment: As pointed out in other answers, this is deprecated as of iOS 5.0

Answer (score 8):

In order to Persist the Unique Identifier you create between installations, you could use the Keychain [Made easy with SSKeychain](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain):  Simply set your UUID as follows:

```
        [SSKeychain setPassword:@"Your UUID" forService:@"com.yourapp.yourcompany" account:@"user"];
```

and then call it again anytime you need it:

```
NSString *retrieveuuid = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"com.yourapp.yourcompany" account:@"user"];
```

Note:  **The services and accounts must match exactly**.

Then, if the App is deleted and reinstalled, the UUID will persist with reinstallation.

If you then want to share this UUID across devices, set up your app to use iCloud.  You can then store the UUID in NSUserDefaults, sync with KeyValueStore, and then set the UUID in the new devices keychain with the code above.

This answer would get extremely long if I typed code for all the above, but plenty of sample code around here to figure it all out.

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget that in iOS 5 uniqueIdentifier will be deprecated you should use CFUUID instead of that

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, Apple has since deprecated the uniqueIdentifier in iOS 5 (as gN0Me mentioned). Here's the relevant TechCrunch article:
http://techcrunch.com/2011/08/19/apple-ios-5-phasing-out-udid/

Apple suggests that you no longer uniquely identify the device but instead identify the *user*. In most cases, this is excellent advice though there are some situations which still require a **globally** unique device ID. These scenarios are quite common in advertising. Hence, I wrote an extremely simple drop-in library which replicates the existing behavior exactly.

In a shameless plug of self promotion, I'll link it here in the hope that someone finds it useful. Also, I welcome all and any feedback/criticism:
http://www.binpress.com/app/myid/591

Nevertheless, in your particular situation I would advise skipping the **globally** unique ID functionality my library provides as it's a bit overkill for your situation. Instead, I would generate a simple CFUUID and store it in NSUserDefaults. This ID would be specific to your application but would allow you to group all the photos for that "app install" in your database.

In other words, by deprecating the uniqueIdentifier method, Apple is suggesting that you don't  identify per device but instead per app *install*. Unless you are operating under specific conditions, chances are the *per app* ID fits your product better anyway.

Comment: Your solution is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Use Apple's GenericKeyChain which is the best solution . Here is the working sample >>https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html

Have idea about KeyChainAccess >>https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.

Answer (score 0):

snippit:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"]; // Will return null in simulator!
NSLog(@"Formatted phone number [%@]", phoneNumber);
```

I [recently] ran this code as-is on OS 2.2.1 [and OS 3.0].

It works as expected when run on the device, and returns my phone number with the full international dialing codes [ 1 in my case].

When run on the simulator, the value [returned] is a null string, so it only works on an actual iPhone device.

I did not test it on an iPod Touch.

...

Ran this code on a different device this week, and got a null value instead of the number.

On further research, it appears that the number returned by this code snippit is the number that is set up in iTunes for the device.

If you didn’t enter the iPhone’s number in iTunes at device activation, or perhaps (as in my case) if the default value wasn’t the iPhone’s number and you clicked OK anyway, such that iTunes doesn’t list the phone number when your iPhone is plugged in, this code will return a null string.

[Above is an edited concatenation of comments I recently posted to another article on this topic at http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2008/11/15/snippet-phone-number/]

Answer (score 0):

I had success with such code:

```
- (NSString *)stringUniqueID {
    NSString *  result;
    CFUUIDRef   uuid;
    CFStringRef uuidStr;
    uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    assert(uuid != NULL);
    uuidStr = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
    assert(uuidStr != NULL);
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", uuidStr];
    assert(result != nil);
    NSLog(@"UNIQUE ID %@", result);
    CFRelease(uuidStr);
    CFRelease(uuid);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAC address as a unique id. Following link will help you

[How can I programmatically get the MAC address of an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone)

Comment: This has been deprecated for years.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't done iphone work, but how about taking a hash of something unique to the phone ... oh, say the phone number?

[Getting iphone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

Comment: That frequently works but will return incorrect information in a significant number of cases.  It gets a phone number, but it's not guaranteed to be the current phone's number, a valid phone number, or even a unique number.

Comment: how often does an iPod Touch have a phone number?

Comment: Phone number is definitely not unique. It is also something that is known by many people, so is a bad choice for securing any sort of data behind a webservice. Further - what happens when you change phone numbers?