# How can I programmatically get the MAC address of an iPhone 3G S?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mac-address

[This question has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone), but it only works on the old iPhone and iPod touch.

On the iPhone 3G S, it gives me "00:00:00:00:00:70", which is incorrect.

Comment: Which interface are you queuing on the 3G S?  Mine hasn't showed up from Rogers yet.  If you don't have an answer by the time mine shows up I'll look at that code again and see what happens on the new device.

Comment: querying....  bah.  Can't edit my comment.  Should have read "What interface are you querying?"

Comment: The MAC address mentioned in the question is for pdp_ip0.

I answered my own question, but thanks for the comments PyjamaSam! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stupid me: I had Wi-Fi turned off. Actually, even if Wi-Fi is turned **on**, but is not currently connected to a network, it doesn't show up!

The Wi-Fi interface appears to be called **en0**, while **pdp_ip0** (the interface for the MAC I mentioned in the question) is the cellular network.