# How does iStat for iPhone get the WiFi MAC & task list

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

[iSTat](http://bjango.com/apps/istat/) shows a list of running tasks and also shows the Mac address of the Wifi connection. I understand that there's a way to get the Mac address via NSHost but it seems to be a private API. Also the task list is a mystery to me. Where do they get all that information from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the MAC address:

[How can I programmatically get the MAC address of an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone)

Still looking for task list.

Comment: but what about the call to ether_ntoa ?
this is private API isn't it?

Comment: rated up for half of the answer... but still no one knows about the task list?