# How to retrieve the WiFi Mac address of a device -- IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uidevice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I programmatically get the MAC address of an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone)

I want to retrieve the WiFi Mac address of a device which we find in Settings --> General --> About --> Wi-Fi Address

How can I fetch it? And will this be unique no matter what network it is?