# Can a native iPhone app access the wifi chip's mac address?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5

Can a native iPhone app access the wifi chip's mac address?

If so what about other unique hardware ids?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In the class `UIDevice`, there was a method `uniqueIdentifier`. But it has been deprecated in iOS 5. You can still use it, but it's a bad idea, as it is expected to disappear.

One replacement is OpenUDID: it is an open source initiative to replace the UDID method.
https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID

Answer (score 0):

Make a UUID and storage it in the users default database

```
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [defaults synchronize];

   CFUUIDRef uuidObj = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
   NSString *user = (NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuidObj);
   CFRelease(uuidObj);

   uuid = user;
   [defaults setObject:uuid forKey:uuidjettec];
   [defaults synchronize];
```

if you need a unique identifier, maybe the MAC address is your solution. you can check this link  [How can I programmatically get the MAC address of an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone)

regards