# iphone :How to create unique ID to identify the user

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my app i want to create unique App ID foe every user..I heard about GUID which is used to create the unique Id for users.so how do i generate this GUID?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

Returns the Unique ID of your iPhone.

If you need to create several UUID, just use this method:

```
+ (NSString *)GetUUID
{
  CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
  CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
  CFRelease(theUUID);
  return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```

**NOTE** : A UUID created by CFUUIDCreate is unique if a user uninstalls and re-installs the app: you will get a new one each time.

Also UUID is deprecated in iOS 5.

Comment: then what is the option in iOS5

Comment: you can use MAC address of your device as X Slash has mentioned !

Answer (score 1):

UUID is deprecated in iOS 5, but you can always use MAC Address

[How can I programmatically get the MAC address of an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone)

Comment: @X Slash, is the MAC addr constant across network interfaces when the user shifts back and forth from Wi-Fi and cellular connections?

Comment: MAC address is fixed for any given network interface. A WiFi network card has a separate MAC address from a cellular network card for instance.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution same as Maulik suggested...

This is about creating unique file names...  But this can be apply to anything...that needs to be unique...

```
NSString *filePath;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SomeDirectoryName"];

//Create unique filename
CFUUIDRef newUniqueId = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
CFStringRef newUniqueIdString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueId);
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString *)newUniqueIdString];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathExtension: @"MOV"];
CFRelease(newUniqueId);
CFRelease(newUniqueIdString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat off topic since you are asking about users, but you might also need something for a unique device (fingerprint). Have a look at [Keychain Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html) and three `kSecAttrAccessible` constants: `kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly`, `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly`, and `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly`.

The constants should help thwart copy/paste attacks assuming Apple generates a value coupled to a device, similar to `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]`. However, I have never verified the behavior in practice.