# Method for getting iPhone information from a Mac App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa

I was tasked with a subject that requires immediate development, but I'm at lost.
The task was to make a Mac App  to get the UDID (and other information) of an iPhone plugged in a Mac and then export it in a csv file. The same thing can be achieved through iTunes or iPhone Configuration Utility, copy-pasting to Excel or Numbers, but it is very time consuming and the users requested something like this:

-User plugs iPhone on Mac

-User runs app.

-iPhone data is fetched and gets exported to a csv file.

The csv file export is already covered, so what I need right now is a method (as Sarah said in the comments) on the Mac SDK that will let me get those information. After hours on google I found out that I can use IOKit to get information from devices connected fror the USB ports, but nothing else came up specifying on how.

Sorry if it is too simple, I think a simple google search can suffice but I still can't find any leads.Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**: I now think that it is not that simple. I've gotten to the point of using IOKit to get information from a USB device using [this sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/USBPrivateDataSample/Listings/USBPrivateDataSample_c.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000456-USBPrivateDataSample_c-DontLinkElementID_4). But after that I have no idea what to do. I'm still reading on the IOKit documentation, but if ever there are others who've encountered this and know the solution it would be a great deal of help.

Comment: so basically you need a method to fetch the UDID?

Comment: yes, and possibly other info as well such as the serial number and WiFi Mac. I think my question is not very clear, I'll edit it. Thanks.

Comment: This question does not contain or concern Objective-C; please do not add that tag.

Comment: @IuliusCæsar
But I need this done in Xcode, hence the obj-c tag. Am I not correct about this? I'm not very good with tags.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Apple's recent announcements that UDIDs will no longer be accessible...

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi yes I am aware of that and we recently changed our unique identifier to a different format. But I think the case here is different, since the information will be extracted from a Mac. Just like the Summary page of iPhone Configuration Utility where the MAC addresses and serial and UDID is displayed, that's what I want to get.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [link](https://gist.github.com/566994) (for UDID and Serial number) and [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone) (for mac addredd). Also

UDID :

> NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];

Comment: I think this is getting the information from an iOS device. Someone messed up with my tags. I need to get the information from a Mac OS X Application. Like when opening up iPhone Configuration Utility, you can find the information on the Summary page. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: you need to mention clearly. the sentence "The task was to get the UDID (and other information) of an iPhone plugged in a Mac" explains that you need details of an iOS device only. Make it clear.

Comment: I got to the IOKit part so the first link (about UDID and Serial Number) seriously helped. +1 for that. Thanks.