# How to identify a device (unique identifier, CFUUIDRef, device token?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Our app allows the users to do a thing once, and only once. Some data is send to the server and the user gets something in return. However, the user can just reinstall the app in order to use this function again.

How do you prevent this from happen? Since "[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]" is deprecated and might cause rejection???, what is the best way to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a long-term method I can use to uniquely identify an iOS device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319275/what-is-a-long-term-method-i-can-use-to-uniquely-identify-an-ios-device)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

> OpenUDID

```
#include "OpenUDID.h"
NSString* openUDID = [OpenUDID value];
```

Get it from here
[Link to repository](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID/)

Comment: Great! Thanks. Two questions. Do I need to confirm with the user somehow, that I save this id? Do I have to add the OpenUDID Seals/logo in my app? Thanks

Comment: Confirm to the user no, add seal logo, i dont think so i never did :D

Comment: Yea but it sucks. It doesn't use ARC!

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus i agree, but for now i cannot see better solutions that are also cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include "OpenUDID.h"
NSString* openUDID = [OpenUDID value];
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using SecureUDID also your problem will solved.SecureUDID is one kind of mechanism and it takes domine name and key as the input. It is more secure and 100% unique. By using this logic if user restart the device or reinstall the application also the UDID never gets changed.