# How to generate a IMEI?

Tags: ios, imei

I need to generate a IMEI in a iOS app since it's used for server-side checking ... and iPod's don't have a actual IMEI. I have searched and all I could find were IMEI validation methods and not how to generate one.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you really need? An unique identifier?

Comment: Yes ... I was using the UDID for testing till now, but It's deprecated. On the server-side is a IMEI validator and that's why I would try to generate a IMEI instead of using the UDID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a UDID as @Larme suggested. Have a look at [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID)

Comment: As I answered @Larme ... IMEI would be preferable. But thanks, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Mac Address is no longer available on devices running iOS7

[How to get iOS device MAC address programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827365/how-to-get-ios-device-mac-address-programmatically/18911557#18911557)