# Catch informations about the ipad in background and send it

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I would like to know if some of theses functions are possible with the IOS sdk.

In background process:

to catch

-the available memory space on the ipad
-number of cpu
-ram size of the ipad
-type of screen
-langage of the user

-HostName
-Ip adress
-bluetooth adress
-name of the ipad
-IOS version
-Installed apps on the Ipad
-memory used by our app

To catch all these data in background and to send it to a web service. Do you think all this, is possible and allowed by the ios sdk ?

Thank you

Comment: Available RAM won't be that useful to you. OS will kill apps to make more RAM for yours as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Most of it is, check the [UIDevice class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html) and the folowing questions:

[iPhone/iPad/OSX: How to get my IP address programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072989/iphone-ipad-osx-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically)

[How to get iOS device MAC address programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827365/how-to-get-ios-device-mac-address-programmatically)

You **can** send this info to your webservice without notifying the user, but it's not a nice thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

- The available memory space on the ipad = **Maybe not tried it but don't see why not**
- Number of CPU = **YES**
- Ram size of the ipad = **YES**
- Type of screen = **Not sure what you mean**
- Language of the user = **YES** (**CAN NOT** send in background to webservice without users permission)
- HostName = **Not sure what you mean** (Whilst I don't know what you mean I can see this not be allowed to be sent without the users permission)
- IP address = **YES** (**CAN NOT** send in background to webservice without users permission)
- bluetooth address = **Not sure what you mean**
- Name of the ipad = **YES** (**CAN NOT** send in background to webservice without users permission)
- iOS version = **YES**
- Installed apps on the Ipad = **NO**
- Memory used by our app = **Maybe never tried but don't see why not**

Basically any personal information about the user you can't send without the users permission.

Answer (score 0):

what you can get, if app is in foreground are below.

1) available memory space on the ipad

2) type of screen andlangage of the user

3) name of the ipad and iOS version

left-over you can't fetch even if app is in foreground.

apple doesn't allow to run app in background to prevent battery consumption, even if, allow then for around 20-30 seconds, when app goes in background from foreground.

Answer (score 0):

[UIDevice currentDevice].model

[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion

[UIDevice currentDevice].name

[UIDevice currentDevice].systemName

[UIDevice currentDevice].localizedModel

[UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom

[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor

[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformType]

[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString]