# iOS - Get ARP table

Tags: ios, iphone, network-programming, mac-address

I am trying to build a network scanner.
I know the procedure so I want to ping all available hosts in the network and then get the **ARP** table so I can map the MAC address for each IP.
I Googled for ARP table but I didn't find any guide how to implement this feature.
I also found these similar questions on Stack overflow:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395041/getting-arp-table-on-iphone-ipad)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258172/how-do-i-query-the-arp-table-on-iphone)

The answer are unclear on how to implement the ARP feature.
Is there any official guide for this one? Is Apple approving the ARP table feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE AFTER  10.2**

Check the library [here](https://github.com/mavris/MacFinder)

I finally got it working so I will post the procedure in detail to save some time for other guys:

1. Go to Applications and right click on Xcode -> Show package contents and browse to: **Developer ▸ Platforms ▸ MacOSX.platform ▸ Developer ▸ SDKs ▸ MacOSX10.10.sdk ▸ usr ▸ include**. From "net" folder copy the `route.h` and `if_types.h` and from the "netinet" folder copy the `if_ether.h` into your Xcode project.
2. Then import the following `.m` and `.h` files:

**MacFinder.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>
#include "if_types.h"

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#include <net/route.h>
#else
#include "route.h"
#endif

#include "if_ether.h"
#include <netinet/in.h>


#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <paths.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

@interface MacFinder : NSObject{

    int nflag;
}

-(NSString*) ip2mac: (char*)ip;

@end
```

**MacFinder.m**

```
#import "MacFinder.h"

@implementation MacFinder
-(NSString*) ip2mac: (char*)ip
{
    int  found_entry = 0;



    NSString *mAddr = nil;
    u_long addr = inet_addr(ip);
    int mib[6];
    size_t needed;
    char *host, *lim, *buf, *next;
    struct rt_msghdr *rtm;
    struct sockaddr_inarp *sin;
    struct sockaddr_dl *sdl;
    extern int h_errno;
    struct hostent *hp;

    mib[0] = CTL_NET;
    mib[1] = PF_ROUTE;
    mib[2] = 0;
    mib[3] = AF_INET;
    mib[4] = NET_RT_FLAGS;
    mib[5] = RTF_LLINFO;
    if (sysctl(mib, 6, NULL, &needed, NULL, 0) < 0)
        err(1, "route-sysctl-estimate");
    if ((buf = malloc(needed)) == NULL)
        err(1, "malloc");
    if (sysctl(mib, 6, buf, &needed, NULL, 0) < 0)
        err(1, "actual retrieval of routing table");


    lim = buf + needed;
    for (next = buf; next < lim; next += rtm->rtm_msglen) {
        rtm = (struct rt_msghdr *)next;
        sin = (struct sockaddr_inarp *)(rtm + 1);
        sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(sin + 1);
        if (addr) {
            if (addr != sin->sin_addr.s_addr)
                continue;
            found_entry = 1;
        }
        if (nflag == 0)
            hp = gethostbyaddr((caddr_t)&(sin->sin_addr),
                               sizeof sin->sin_addr, AF_INET);
        else
            hp = 0;
        if (hp)
            host = hp->h_name;
        else {
            host = "?";
            if (h_errno == TRY_AGAIN)
                nflag = 1;
        }



        if (sdl->sdl_alen) {

            u_char *cp = LLADDR(sdl);

            mAddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", cp[0], cp[1], cp[2], cp[3], cp[4], cp[5]];


            //  ether_print((u_char *)LLADDR(sdl));
        }
        else

            mAddr = nil;



    }


    if (found_entry == 0) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return mAddr;
    }




}
@end
```

3. Then import the **MacFinder.h** file in your `ViewController`
4. Example how to use it for each host you want to find the **MAC Address**:

`MacFinder *mc = [[MacFinder alloc]init];
NSString *mac = [mc ip2mac:"192.168.10.24"];
NSLog(@"Mac:%@",mac);`

**If you still having trouble [here](https://medium.com/rocknnull/ios-from-ip-to-mac-address-1e3726ff6d2b#.mdrrodsia) is tutorial and [here](https://github.com/mavris/MacFinder) the full working project (Including the necessary files)**

Comment: That call to `malloc` is a leak. The call to `gethostbyaddr` looks redundant. Otherwise, this works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Please feel free to update the answer and fix the leak!

Comment: I followed these instructions step by step but the mac address is always nil, because the found_entry int is always 0. Does anybody have an idea? (the IP is 100% valid)

Comment: @user3191334 If you still having trouble  here is tutorial https://medium.com/rocknnull/ios-from-ip-to-mac-address-1e3726ff6d2b#.mdrrodsia and here https://github.com/mavris/MacFinder  the full working project (Including the necessary files)

Comment: broken in ios 10.2

Comment: We opened an issue in order to solve the problem. https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan/issues/3#issuecomment-267268987

Comment: Xcode 8 eliminates the need to copy macOS header files to iOS. It provides `sockaddr_inarp` in `netinet/if_ether.h`.

Comment: Hi BlackM, is there still a way to get the ARP table in iOS13?