# how do i get arp cache table from iPhone for iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, network-programming, mac-address, arp

I'm trying to write a simple network scanner from iphone where-in i just want to get the **ARP-cache** table of Router. The below given links give me some idea on this issue

1. [iOS - Get ARP table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226522/ios-get-arp-table)
2. [How do I query the ARP table on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258172/how-do-i-query-the-arp-table-on-iphone#)

But from ios8 does not allow the use of header file

> sys/sysctl.h

Hence do not know how to proceed on this . Any other work around to get router arp cache table ?