# iOS: How can I obtain MACAddress of other devices in Socket?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

When I am using socket programming to connect my iOS device to some devices (intelligent switch), I don't know how to obtain the MacAddress of the devices.

I know that the following code can work in Linux, but in Objective-C, there is no "`SIOCGIFHWMAC`" Parameter in `ioctl()` function and no "`ifr_hwaddr`" in `struct ifreq`. So, how can I obtain the MacAddress?

```
struct ifreq req;

memset(&g_CtrlAdpter, 0, sizeof(g_CtrlAdpter));

int Sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
memcpy(req.ifr_name, Device, strlen(Device));

int ErrNo = ioctl(Sock, SIOCGIFHWMAC, &req, sizeof(req));

if (-1 != ErrNo)
{
    memcpy(MACAddress, req.ifr_hwaddr, MAC_ADDR_LEN);
}
```

Comment: You will probably have more luck querying the ARP table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226522/ios-get-arp-table