# How do i get MAC address on iOS 10?

Tags: macos, ios10, arp

When my iphone is connected to a WiFi network, I pings each IP on the network and builds the ARP Cache and then reads the MAC address from the ARP Cache table like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258172/how-do-i-query-the-arp-table-on-iphone). 
It works well before ios 10, but when i run this code on ios 10 machine, i can't get the right MAC address, always return 02:00:00:00:00:00! But it can work well on iphone 7 simulator!!! I don't know how it happen! Is there something change about ARP API?

Comment: @JAL Cool, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify devices,Apple recommend to use **identifierForVendor**. May be you managed to get the MAC address post iOS 7 till iOS 9 but it's not guaranteed for future release.So better use identifierForVendor as recommended by Apple.Here is the release note of iOS 7 from Apple.

> In iOS 7 and later, if you ask for the MAC address of an iOS device,
>   the system returns the value 02:00:00:00:00:00. If you need to
>   identify the device, use the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice
>   instead. (Apps that need an identifier for their own advertising
>   purposes should consider using the advertisingIdentifier property of
>   ASIdentifierManager instead.)

Comment: Thanks,but identifierForVendor can only identify ios devices,i need to  identify other devices!

Comment: Other devices in different platforms ? There you can continue using MAC address right. ?

Comment: I have found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283688/mac-addresses-in-ios-10-2),thanks anyway!