# List the available ip-address and name of the devices in the same network in iOS(Objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, network-programming

I am developing the iOS application using objective-c.The main usage of the application is communicating with wifi enabled hardware device.It's uses UDP protocol.Now the problem is all the hardware device are connected with my office network and my iPad also connected with my office network.Now i want to list the available ip-address in the same network.So many duplicate questions are there but no place i found the solution for this.please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS application can find available ip-address in same network using command `arp -a`. Unfortunately, ARP doesn't support iOS.

But I recommend you this question would be helpful..

[iOS - Get ARP table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226522/ios-get-arp-table)

Comment: Hi mqz.kim thanks for your link. In this link i can able to get the mac address.But i want to list the DNS name and ip-address of the device available in the same network.Thanks.

Comment: I had an experience what you want exactly..
If you know your own IP address, you can get the ARP table by changing the fourth address number from 1 to 255 and typing it.