# How to get MAC address programmatically in my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C, actually I want to display mac address when my device is connected to WiFi and I have seen many answers regarding this but I am unable to get what I want. So please can anyone guide me in form of tutorial. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827365/how-to-get-ios-device-mac-address-programmatically

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya i have seen the link you provided but i have already gone through it but that code is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mac address is unavailable from ios 7 and up.

Apple Said

> In iOS 7 and later, if you ask for the MAC address of an iOS device,
>   the system returns the value 02:00:00:00:00:00. If you need to
>   identify the device, use the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice
>   instead. (Apps that need an identifier for their own advertising
>   purposes should consider using the advertisingIdentifier property of
>   ASIdentifierManager instead.)

[Check bottom of the page into Apple Document.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1)

So better solution for that.
Following code returns unique address.

```
#import "UIDevice+Identifier.h"

- (NSString *) identifierForVendor1
{
     if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)]) {
          return [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
     }
     return @"";
}
```

Calling Method

```
NSString *like_UDID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor1]];

NSLog(@"%@",like_UDID);
```

[Also another solution visit HERE](http://sugartin.info/2013/11/26/get-ip-or-mac-address-of-ios-device-simulator/)

**Edited**

UIDevice+Identifier.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIDevice (IdentifierAddition)
- (NSString *) identifierForVendor1;
@end
```

UIDevice+Identifier.m

```
#import "UIDevice+Identifier.h"

@implementation UIDevice (IdentifierAddition)
- (NSString *) identifierForVendor1
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)]) {
        return [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    }
    return @"";
}

@end
```

Calling above Function.

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIDevice+Identifier.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *like_UDID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                         [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor1]];


    NSLog(@"%@",like_UDID);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Should i add this code in a NSObject class

Comment: No you need to add `UIDevice` class category.

Comment: @BalajiPraveen I think now your problem solved...

Comment: [m:10:9: 'UIDevice+Identifier.h' file not found]  showing me this error

Comment: You just follow my above edited answer.It might be solve your problem.

Comment: Its working,thank you so much