# How to find MAC address in iOS 7 and above programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on a network security based ios app. I need to find the device's MAC address which is used to register the device at router level. Once registration is complete then the router allows the network traffic coming from that MAC address to pass through.

Now, the problem is, in ios 7 or later we can't get the device mac address, as per the following post:
[stackoverflow:Mac address is unavailable from ios 7 and up.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397089/how-to-get-mac-address-programmatically-in-my-ios-app)

Can anyone suggest me any alternative way to find MAC address in ios using C or Objective-C or using any other way.

EDIT:
I know that this question has been asked and answered but I am looking for any alternative way by which we can do this.

Comment: As the pust suggest you can't find the MAC address any more. Apple has removed access to it to protect the privacy of there users. If there is a way to get it the code will not be AppStore save.

Comment: I am using native c programming also in my app, so is there any way in C through which I can do this?

Comment: The old code to get the MAC address was also using C, Apple made sure you can net get any device specific identifier since iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can't anymore due to a change in Apple's privacy controls.

Comment: Is there no alternative that can be used?

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted as it is the correct answer.

If there was an alternative, then that would not meet the goal of protecting the user's privacy.

Comment: Use an exploit, which is illegal.