# How to get device Wi-Fi MAC address in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, networking, react-native

As the title.

I want get device `Mac Address` on iOS(can find on `iPhone Settings --> General --> About -> Wi-Fi Address`) and `Android` with `ReactNative`.

thanks.

Comment: An app cannot access the MAC address on iOS for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you're wondering how to access a bit of system information with React Native, you could write a small native module that calls the same functions you would as if you were writing a UIKit app -- there's nothing unique about React Native in many cases.

But on iOS when you ask for the MAC you will always get back `02:00:00:00:00:00` -- what you are asking for is not feasible. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911557/454967.