# Does Apple have an API i can use to request and send the wifi MAC address I'm connected to?

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, ios7, xamarin.ios

is there an API i can use to request and send the wifi MAC address I'm connected to? I'm in the process of creating an app and would like to use the locations wifi MAC address as an identifier. Meaning guarantee user is at that particular location

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get iOS device MAC address programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827365/how-to-get-ios-device-mac-address-programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

No. Apple removed that feature a few version ago to protect the privacy of the owners. The replacement is `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor`. You can learn more about IdentifierForVendor at the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me give a follow up question because I'm not the person writing the code but I know what's needed and And that particular API would've been perfect. This replacement what does it do exactly? And if I want the app to work with wifi and only works with wifi at several locations. What do you recommend ? Any suggestions

Comment: I updated my answer with the link to the documentation for IdentifierForVendor. I have no recommendations for you on limiting your app to work only on wifi in specific locations.