# how to get device udid in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, device, udid

I developing iPhone application. In this app i need to get device udid. In simulator working fine, but in iphone device not getting correct value, the values getting 0.

The code are following;

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [device uniqueIdentifier];
```

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.macworld.com/article/2031573/apple-sets-may-1-deadline-for-udid-iphone-5-app-changes.html

Comment: Why are you using UDID ? It is deprecated now. and apple has resticted to use this.

Comment: ok, how to get iPhone unique identifier? can you help me.

Comment: how to get unique id from iPhone device?

Answer (score 3):

As we know **uniqueIdentifier is deprecated in iOS 5.0** so docs recommend you to use [CFUUID](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFUUIDCreate)

instead. You can get CFUUID using

```
CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
NSString *uuidString = (NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL,uuidRef);
CFRelease(uuidRef);
```

Please save the uuidString in user defaults or in other place because you can not generate the same uuidString again.

You can use **mac address** also in place of this as an alternative [how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/howcan-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone)
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Actually, please don't use hardware identifiers: they suffer from precisely the same privacy concerns that resulted in the need for Apple to deprecate and eventually ban the use of UUID.

Answer (score 0):

UDID is deprecated. From 1st May 2013, Apple is not approving any app that access uniqueIdentifier. Instead you can use ASIIDentifier or NSUUID.Or MAC address.

I have followed this approach in `IDManager` class,
This is a collection from different solutions. KeyChainUtil is a wrapper to read from keychain.

```
#define kBuggyASIID             @"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

+ (NSString *) getUniqueID {
    if (NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager")) {
        NSString * asiID = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
        if ([asiID compare:kBuggyASIID] == NSOrderedSame) {
            NSLog(@"Error: This device return buggy advertisingIdentifier.");
            return [IDManager getUniqueID];
        } else {
            return asiID;
        }

    } else {
        return [IDManager getUniqueUUID];
    }
}


+ (NSString *) getUniqueUUID {
    NSError * error;
    NSString * uuid = [KeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:kBuyassUser andServiceName:kIdOgBetilngService error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error geting unique UUID for this device! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return nil;
    }
    if (!uuid) {
        DLog(@"No UUID found. Creating a new one.");
        uuid = [IDManager GetUUID];
        uuid = [Util md5String:uuid];
        [KeychainUtils storeUsername:kBuyassUser andPassword:uuid forServiceName:kIdOgBetilngService updateExisting:YES error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error geting unique UUID for this device! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return nil;
        }
    }
    return uuid;
}

/* NSUUID is after iOS 6. */
+ (NSString *)GetUUID
{
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}

#pragma mark - MAC address
// Return the local MAC addy
// Courtesy of FreeBSD hackers email list
// Last fallback for unique identifier
+ (NSString *) getMACAddress
{
    int                 mib[6];
    size_t              len;
    char                *buf;
    unsigned char       *ptr;
    struct if_msghdr    *ifm;
    struct sockaddr_dl  *sdl;

    mib[0] = CTL_NET;
    mib[1] = AF_ROUTE;
    mib[2] = 0;
    mib[3] = AF_LINK;
    mib[4] = NET_RT_IFLIST;

    if ((mib[5] = if_nametoindex("en0")) == 0) {
        printf("Error: if_nametoindex error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (sysctl(mib, 6, NULL, &len, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Error: sysctl, take 1\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((buf = malloc(len)) == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Memory allocation error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (sysctl(mib, 6, buf, &len, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Error: sysctl, take 2\n");
        free(buf); // Thanks, Remy "Psy" Demerest
        return NULL;
    }

    ifm = (struct if_msghdr *)buf;
    sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(ifm + 1);
    ptr = (unsigned char *)LLADDR(sdl);
    NSString *outstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", *ptr, *(ptr+1), *(ptr+2), *(ptr+3), *(ptr+4), *(ptr+5)];

    free(buf);
    return outstring;
}
```