# How do I programmatically retrieve device's mac address on the same WIFI network

Tags: ios, objective-c, ip, wifi, mac-address

I read the post [How can I programmatically get the MAC address of an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone), but I am still not sure if I can do it with any devices other than an Iphone that are connected to the same WIFI network. I can be able to get a list of IP address from these devices on the same WIFI network, so can I retrieve every mac address from each IP address ?

Comment: @RicardoSánchez-Sáez It looks like the other question is talking about the MAC address and IP address of the device the program is running on. This question is asking about devices over the network.

Comment: You may be right after all. I'll delete my answer and the duplicate flag. Not sure how to get MAC addresses of devices connected to the same network. Maybe you can check `ng-airodump` source code and see if you can translate their approach to iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to just sniff the network for it, read random packets for header infomation. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, apps like netstumbler and ethereal should be able to do what you want (they are both open source)

Comment: by saying sniff the network for it. did you mean making a tcp connection and then get the header information ?

Comment: If it's unencrypted or you have the key, you can just sniff wireless packets directly using something like airodump.