# Get MAC address in mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

I need to retrieve all available MAC addresses available in the current mobile device, and if possible the currently active network card IP address.

- How can I get the currently active network card MAC and IP address in Delphi XE5 / XE6 ?

Comment: I think [this post][1] will clear things up for you!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone

Comment: @user3631728: comments do not support reference-style links, use inline links instead. When adding a new comment, click on the `help` link to see the proper syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up @wholegrain's answer and this info from the link posted by @user3631728 [How can I programmatically get the MAC address of an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone):

> "In iOS 7 and later, if you ask for the MAC address of an iOS device,
>   the system returns the value 02:00:00:00:00:00. If you need to
>   identify the device, use the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice
>   instead. (Apps that need an identifier for their own advertising
>   purposes should consider using the advertisingIdentifier property of
>   ASIdentifierManager instead.)"

if this this would be suffice, you can do something like this for IOS:

```
Uses
  {$IFDEF IOS}
    iOSApi.UIKit;
  {$ENDIF}

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  {$IFDEF IOS}
    Device    : UIDevice;
  {$ENDIF}
begin
  {$IFDEF IOS}
    Device := TUIDevice.Wrap(TUIDevice.OCClass.currentDevice);
    ShowMessage(Device.uniqueIdentifier.UTF8String);
    ShowMessage(Device.identifierForVendor.UUIDString.UTF8String);
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Comment: Seems like I shall have to go this way if there is no other option :|
Thanks about the good hint ! :)

Answer (score 1):

For Android:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS7, its not possible to retrieve device's Mac address.