# How to get MAC address of a connected WiFi Device?

Tags: ios

I want **iOS** equivalent code of the following **android** version.

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String address = info.getMacAddress();
```

I am able to get the `ip` from the following:

```
WifiManager * manager = [[WifiManager alloc ] init];
NSMutableDictionary *connectedWiFiInfo = [manager getWifiInformation];
```

But, this `ip`, `ssid`, etc can be changed after I connect the WiFi device to MAC. Therefore, I am looking for MAC address.

Comment: Check out this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone

Comment: Do you want to do this in swift of Objective C?

Comment: @abhishek any one is good for me as long as i can bridge that swift code to objective c. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Rajatp thanks for your reply, i will try with that link and revert back.