# API to get an iPhones unique ID?

Tags: iphone

Two part question:

- Does the iPhone have a unique ID other than it's MAC address?
- If so, is there an API call I can use to get it?

(hopefully this isn't a duplicate, I couldn't find anything on SO)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227590/unique-identifier-for-an-iphone-app

Comment: @Ville, great, thanks! I'll vote to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The iPhone does have a unique identifier, called the UDID (this is the same identifier used when setting up a device for development or when doing ad hoc distribution).  You can retrieve it as so:

```
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;
```

Comment: Just to inform the late comers to this question, the said method is now deprecated in `iOS5`.