# Getting Device ID or Mac Address in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, device, mac-address

I have an application that uses rest to communicate to a server, i would like to obtain the iphones either mac address or device ID for uniqueness validation, how can this be done?

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045608/api-to-get-an-iphones-unique-id

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` is guaranteed to be unique to each device.

Comment: For those new comers to this question, the UDID API is deprecated in iOS 5. To get a unique identifier, you need to turn to iPhones' MAC address instead.

Comment: @diwup, the MAC addr changes depending if the user is on a cellular connection vs Wi-Fi connection right? Or is it the same across both types of network interfaces?

Comment: what is the alternative not deprecated ?

Comment: use `identifierForVendor` instead in iOS 6+, returns NSUUID object

Comment: Here's a great article with alternatives: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/

Answer (score 40):

> uniqueIdentifier (Deprecated in iOS 5.0. Instead, create a unique identifier specific to your app.)

The docs recommend use of [CFUUIDCreate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFUUIDCreate) instead of `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]`

So here is how you generate an unique id in your app

```
CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
NSString *uuidString = (NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL,uuidRef);

CFRelease(uuidRef);
```

Note that you have to save the uuidString in user defaults or in other place because you can not generate the same uuidString again.

You can use [UIPasteboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html) to store your generated uuid. And if the app will be deleted and reinstalled you can read from  UIPasteboard the old uuid. The paste board will be wiped out when the device will be erased.

In iOS 6 they have introduced the [NSUUID Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that is designed to create UUIDs strings

Also they added in iOS 6 `@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSUUID *identifierForVendor` to the [UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) class

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the
>   same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned
>   for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for
>   apps on different devices regardless of vendor.
>
> The value of this property may be nil if the app is running in the
>   background, before the user has unlocked the device the first time
>   after the device has been restarted. If the value is nil, wait and get
>   the value again later.

Also in iOS 6 you can use [ASIdentifierManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012654) class from AdSupport.framework. There you have

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSUUID *advertisingIdentifier
```

> Discussion Unlike the identifierForVendor property of the UIDevice,
>   the same value is returned to all vendors. This identifier may
>   change—for example, if the user erases the device—so you should not
>   cache it.
>
> The value of this property may be nil if the app is running in the
>   background, before the user has unlocked the device the first time
>   after the device has been restarted. If the value is nil, wait and get
>   the value again later.

Edit:

Pay attention that the `advertisingIdentifier` may return

> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

because there seems to be a bug in iOS. Related question: [The advertisingIdentifier and identifierForVendor return "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605257/the-advertisingidentifier-and-identifierforvendor-return-00000000-0000-0000-000)

Answer (score 18):

For a Mac Adress you could use

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MacAddressHelper : NSObject

+ (NSString *)getMacAddress;

@end
```

implentation

```
#import "MacAddressHelper.h"
#import <sys/socket.h>
#import <sys/sysctl.h>
#import <net/if.h>
#import <net/if_dl.h>

@implementation MacAddressHelper

+ (NSString *)getMacAddress
{
  int                 mgmtInfoBase[6];
  char                *msgBuffer = NULL;
  size_t              length;
  unsigned char       macAddress[6];
  struct if_msghdr    *interfaceMsgStruct;
  struct sockaddr_dl  *socketStruct;
  NSString            *errorFlag = NULL;

  // Setup the management Information Base (mib)
  mgmtInfoBase[0] = CTL_NET;        // Request network subsystem
  mgmtInfoBase[1] = AF_ROUTE;       // Routing table info
  mgmtInfoBase[2] = 0;              
  mgmtInfoBase[3] = AF_LINK;        // Request link layer information
  mgmtInfoBase[4] = NET_RT_IFLIST;  // Request all configured interfaces

  // With all configured interfaces requested, get handle index
  if ((mgmtInfoBase[5] = if_nametoindex("en0")) == 0) 
    errorFlag = @"if_nametoindex failure";
  else
  {
    // Get the size of the data available (store in len)
    if (sysctl(mgmtInfoBase, 6, NULL, &length, NULL, 0) < 0) 
      errorFlag = @"sysctl mgmtInfoBase failure";
    else
    {
      // Alloc memory based on above call
      if ((msgBuffer = malloc(length)) == NULL)
        errorFlag = @"buffer allocation failure";
      else
      {
        // Get system information, store in buffer
        if (sysctl(mgmtInfoBase, 6, msgBuffer, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
          errorFlag = @"sysctl msgBuffer failure";
      }
    }
  }
  // Befor going any further...
  if (errorFlag != NULL)
  {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorFlag);
    return errorFlag;
  }
  // Map msgbuffer to interface message structure
  interfaceMsgStruct = (struct if_msghdr *) msgBuffer;
  // Map to link-level socket structure
  socketStruct = (struct sockaddr_dl *) (interfaceMsgStruct + 1);  
  // Copy link layer address data in socket structure to an array
  memcpy(&macAddress, socketStruct->sdl_data + socketStruct->sdl_nlen, 6);  
  // Read from char array into a string object, into traditional Mac address format
  NSString *macAddressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", 
                                macAddress[0], macAddress[1], macAddress[2], 
                                macAddress[3], macAddress[4], macAddress[5]];
  //NSLog(@"Mac Address: %@", macAddressString);  
  // Release the buffer memory
  free(msgBuffer);
  return macAddressString;
}

@end
```

Use:

```
NSLog(@"MAC address: %@",[MacAddressHelper getMacAddress]);
```

Comment: that's a lot of work to get the mac address

Comment: Is using of Mac addesses is legal? If UUID were privacy hole, then MacAddress can be even bigger hole.

Comment: for which interface is that mac address? wifi? 3G?

Comment: Since iOS7 this is NOT working anymore. As the release notes of iOS 7 states:

Two low-level networking APIs that used to return a MAC address now return the fixed value 02:00:00:00:00:00. The APIs in question are sysctl (NET_RT_IFLIST) and ioctl (SIOCGIFCONF). Developers using the value of the MAC address should migrate to identifiers such as -[UIDevice identifierForVendor]. This change affects all apps running on iOS 7.

Objective-C Runtime
Notes

Comment: @Nathan Sakoetoe: I am getting 02:00:00:00:00:00 Mac address. Is there any other solution to get correct mac address in iOS 8.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
NSUUID *id = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
NSLog(@"ID: %@", id);
```

Answer (score 4):

In IOS 5 `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` is deprecated.

It's better to use `-identifierForVendor` or `-identifierForAdvertising`.

A lot of useful information can be found here:

[iOS6 UDID - What advantages does identifierForVendor have over identifierForAdvertising?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836225/ios6-udid-what-advantages-does-identifierforvendor-have-over-identifierforadve)

Answer (score -10):

### Here, We can find mac address for IOS device using Asp.net C# Code...

.aspx.cs

```
-
 var UserDeviceInfo = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToLower(); // User's Iphone/Ipad Info.

var UserMacAdd = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;         // User's Iphone/Ipad Mac Address



  GetMacAddressfromIP macadd = new GetMacAddressfromIP();
        if (UserDeviceInfo.Contains("iphone;"))
        {
            // iPhone                
            Label1.Text = UserDeviceInfo;
            Label2.Text = UserMacAdd;
            string Getmac = macadd.GetMacAddress(UserMacAdd);
            Label3.Text = Getmac;
        }
        else if (UserDeviceInfo.Contains("ipad;"))
        {
            // iPad
            Label1.Text = UserDeviceInfo;
            Label2.Text = UserMacAdd;
            string Getmac = macadd.GetMacAddress(UserMacAdd);
            Label3.Text = Getmac;
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = UserDeviceInfo;
            Label2.Text = UserMacAdd;
            string Getmac = macadd.GetMacAddress(UserMacAdd);
            Label3.Text = Getmac;
        }
```

### .class File

```
public string GetMacAddress(string ipAddress)
    {
        string macAddress = string.Empty;
        if (!IsHostAccessible(ipAddress)) return null;

        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

            Process process = new Process();

            processStartInfo.FileName = "arp";

            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;

            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            processStartInfo.Arguments = "-a " + ipAddress;

            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

            int Counter = -1;

            while (Counter <= -1)
            {                  
                    Counter = macAddress.Trim().ToLower().IndexOf("mac address", 0);
                    if (Counter > -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    macAddress = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                    if (macAddress != "")
                    {
                        string[] mac = macAddress.Split(' ');
                        if (Array.IndexOf(mac, ipAddress) > -1)                                
                        {
                            if (mac[11] != "")
                            {
                                macAddress = mac[11].ToString();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            process.WaitForExit();
            macAddress = macAddress.Trim();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Failed because:" + e.ToString());

        }
        return macAddress;

    }
```

Comment: tried to improve the code formatting - not entirely successful, as you see ;-) Please edit and improve

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C# but with objective-c and the Apple SDK!
Wrong answer -1