# How to get the mac_ip_address of iphone device present in setting>general>about/wi-Fi address?

Tags: iphone

I want to print the mac_ip_address of iphone device present in the setting>general>about/wi-Fi address.

how can i get that address, please let me know if any one know.

Answer (score 0):

[IPHONE SDK Getting Device ID or Mac Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110278/iphone-sdk-getting-device-id-or-mac-address)

[How can I programmatically get the MAC address of an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone)

Comment: can you tell me how can i do it for iphone