# Windows Phone 8 - Mac Address

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I know it wasn't possible to retrieve the Mac Address of the WIFI adapter in Windows Phone 7 - 7.5, but is it possible in Windows Phone 8? If so, how?

Comment: I expect not, I dont know what you wan't to do with it, but for Identity you can better use the UDID http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975315/get-unique-device-id-udid-under-windows-phone-8

Comment: It is for Identity, but for all other platforms we also use the mac address so it would be nice to maintain some coherence in that part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code:

```
Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceList InterfacesList = new Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceList();
```

You can obtain all Interfaces connected in your Device.

You want obtain all informations of every connected interfaces with that :

```
foreach (Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceInfo specificInterface in InterfacesList)
    {
        if (specificInterface.InterfaceType == Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("This interface is a Wifi Interface :");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Bandwidth :" + specificInterface.Bandwidth);
        Console.WriteLine("Characteristics :" + specificInterface.Characteristics);
        Console.WriteLine("Description :" + specificInterface.Description);
        Console.WriteLine("InterfaceName :" + specificInterface.InterfaceName);
        Console.WriteLine("InterfaceType :" + specificInterface.InterfaceType);

    }
```

You can go to the MSDN for more information about [NetworkInterfaceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterfaceinfo%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

But, They are not MAC Adress information! you can use "Description", it is the ID of the network card...

Comment: I know is unique In the device (Lumia 920) but I don't know if is totally Unique.

But, You can create an Very_Unique_Id for your card with guid and description Card combine : string UniqueCardId = GUID + CARDDESCRIPTION;