# get unique ID of WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

when trying to get imei number null exception occurs. when running in windows phone emulator.

//Please check this

```
        object uniqueId;
        var hexString = string.Empty;
        if (DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out uniqueId))
            hexString = BitConverter.ToString((byte[])uniqueId).Replace("-",     string.Empty);
        MessageBox.Show("myDeviceID:" + hexString);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this issue with returning the null value.

```
In WMAppManifest.xml -> Capabilities tab -> switch on ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE
```

Answer (score 0):

In this link, he used `GetValue` instead of `TryGetValue` and its working :
[Get Unique Device ID (UDID) under Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975315/get-unique-device-id-udid-under-windows-phone-8)