# Is there a unique windows device id?

Tags: windows-phone-8

i m new here in windows development ,any help will be fine for me

Do windows devices have a unique id and if so, what is a simple way to access it   via c#?

Comment: Should probably read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975315/get-unique-device-id-udid-under-windows-phone-8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893746/udid-for-windows-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a property called `DeviceUniqueId` within the [DeviceExtendedProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class. You could simply retrieve that value as:

```
DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId")
```

For more:

- [Get Unique Device ID (UDID) under Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975315/)
- [How to Get Unique Device ID from Windows Phone 8 Using C#?](http://abundantcode.com/how-to-get-unique-device-id-from-windows-phone-using-c/)