# iOS 6 use of UDIDs for push notifications forbidden?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, apple-push-notifications, udid

Starting May 1st, 2013, **[Apple will stop accepting apps that access unique device identifiers (UDIDs)](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=3212013a)**. Sounds like `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`, will no longer get passed a UDID as the device token; but so far, this doesn't seem to be the case in iOS 6.0.

To get around the issue and hedge the risk of my app getting rejected, I found **[this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836225/ios6-udid-what-advantages-does-identifierforvendor-have-over-identifierforadve)**, where they suggest using `ASIdentifierManager` to check if the user has enabled ad tracking for the app and then get the `advertisingIdentifier`, and use it as the device token. Should I be doing that inside `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` before registering the device for push notifications on my servers or simply trust whatever I get passed as `deviceToken`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no need for you to be switching so eagerly away from UDIDs.  Apple is explicitly removing applications that use UDIDs, however the APS system doesn't use UDIDs, it uses device tokens.  From the documentation on that method:

> deviceToken
>
> A token that identifies the device to APS. The token is an
> opaque data type because that is the form that the provider needs to
> submit to the APS servers when it sends a notification to a device.
> The APS servers require a binary format for performance reasons.
>
> **Note that the device token is different from the uniqueIdentifier property
> of UIDevice** because, for security and privacy reasons, it must change
> when the device is wiped.

All is well in APNS-land.  Carry on.