# AppStore Submission denied - Apps are not permitted to use the UDID neither uniqueIdentifier

Tags: ios, submit, uniqueidentifier, udid

I have been a week without progress with this. I have read a thousand forums and can not find the solution.

I updated the frameworks Flurry, BugSense and CorePlot. This has not worked.

I searched 'uniqueIdentifier' and 'UDID' in my code and there are no matches.

How I can know where the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If its not in your code then it has to be in one of those libraries. I'm sure its not flurry and you can probably search the source of core plot so maybe its bug sense

Comment: possible duplicate of [App rejected, but I don't use UDID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409966/app-rejected-but-i-dont-use-udid)

Answer (score 0):

Find the class that use the UDID in your project. You could use the terminal to do so.

Example:

```
find . | grep -v .svn  | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep uniqueIdentifier
```

Replace UDID with UUID.

With Reference to this post: [Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489079/apps-are-not-permitted-to-access-the-udid-and-must-not-use-the-uniqueidentifier)

Try this:

```
The problem is that your project still refer to the old SDK and it compiles the code with your old sdk methods including the UDID which apple rejects.
Fix it in your build properties of SEARCH PATH Framework Search Paths Library Search Paths
remove unnecessary values such as old sdk path and put there your current sdk path
clean all project's files: Window->Organizer->Project - delete your project Product->Clean
Now rebuild it and resubmit it to apple.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

I have already run this command on my project (in the root, where I have the .h file and the .m file., and where I have the images) and there are no matches.

I have searched for 'uniqueIdentifier' and 'UDID' in my code and I find nothing.

What I can do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I fixed the issue.

I deleted the xcworkspace file and I recompiled the project.

Thank you so much.