# Only Show certain information on a user's IPad/IPhone with their Apple account

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there a way in iOS to check if a user has access to external data by tieing it to their apple account on their iPad or iPhone?  I would initially get their account information and store it externally, and recheck this database when they try to protected information that should only be seen on that users account.

Comment: You can store a UIDocument or key/value pair in the user's iCloud account to accomplish this, but it won't work for users that don't have iCloud.

Comment: Can you grab the Apple account username and device identifier?

Comment: You can't get their username. You can get their identifier here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836225/ios6-udid-what-advantages-does-identifierforvendor-have-over-identifierforadve