# Sharing identifier on iOS Apps

Tags: ios, filesystems, udid

this is my goal: i've to associate an  UUID to each mobile device, storing it in file system.
I'd like to use this UUID as credential for my proprietaries apps, both for android and iOS.
For example: i install two apps in my device. I want this apps utilize this UIID in the authentication process.
Is this possible for iOS ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Might [openUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) be a suitable replacement for you?

Comment: in brief: use keystore that will store pseudo-UDID, I'm using https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security and CFUUID as UDID replacement

Answer (score 0):

UDID is no longer available after iOS 5:
But this is a list of different alternatives for UDID that you can use in your in your iOS app:

- **OpenUDID** is meant as a drop-in replacement; so it’s really the
  closest thing outside the common API. Pros: It mimics the behavior of
  UDID: same format, same attempt at persistence, etc… in addition, it 
  has a built-in opt-out mechanism that will hopefully educate
  developers to deal with this case, and at least put user privacy
  concerns back inside the cycle. Cons: It only works well if it is
  widely adopted, which appears to be the case today. Risk: That Apple 
  actually meant to clamp down on sharing any sort of unique
  identifier, in which case, OpenUDID might be questioned

  https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID/blob/master/README.md
- **UIDevice identifierForVendor** introduced in iOS 6 would work for your
  purposes.  identifierForVendor is an alphanumeric string that
  uniquely identifies a device to the app’s vendor. (read-only) The
  value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same
  vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for
  apps onthe same device that come from different vendors, and for apps
  on different devices regardles of vendor.  Available in iOS 6.0 and
  later and declared in UIDevice.h

  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

  [iOS6 UDID - What advantages does identifierForVendor have over identifierForAdvertising?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836225/ios6-udid-what-advantages-does-identifierforvendor-have-over-identifierforadve)

Comment: Probably the solution is KeyChain:

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your answer before, the Keychain could be a solution for that, notice that the data from keychain will be removed from the device in case that the user erase the device. Otherwise will permit. The keychain can save anything that obeys NSCoding [keychain access](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/03/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html) The link has a simple example of how to use access to the keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you response Manuel, very detailed. Probably i have not explained my question very well. This UUID is generated by an external functionality, both for Android and iOS devices. So i can't decide which format associate to it. I have to store this UUID in the device file system and use it as credential for authentication in proprietary apps.

Example

I recorded my android device and stored in file system the UUID 550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000.

I recorded my iOS device and stored in file system the UUID 112X8700-e35F-31R5-q798-115994130000.

The proprietary apps "MyApp" and "YourApp" are availables both in Android App Store and iOS App Store.

So i install "MyApp" and "YourApp" in my devices (Android and iOS).

When i run "MyApp" and/or "YourApp", in Android i use UUID 550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000 for authentication for both the applications.

When i run "MyApp" and/or "YourApp", in iOS i use UUID UUID 112X8700-e35F-31R5-q798-115994130000 for authentication for both the applications.

I'm confident about the fact that this is possible for Android, because it's possible sharing data/files among apps. But i'm doubtful about iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the solution is KeyChain: 
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-12-dumping-keychain-data