# Is there a way to somehow get a unique ID for an iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, ios7

I am looking for some way to disallow users from my app (ban them for not following rules for example). If I can detect some kind of phone id that is constant, this would be perfect since I can just check for it at the start of app and if it matches a "banned" id, not allow the app to proceed. I looked into **identifierForVendor** from **UIDevice** class but it appears that this is not constant? It looks like if the user of app deletes all my apps and reinstalls, the restriction would go away.

Basically I am just looking for an id that would be constant, no matter if a user deletes my apps or not. Something to recognize a user by (well a phone by). I am supporting iOS7 and above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19179799/397817

Comment: Why don't you get device token for your device? Register your device for remoteNotifcations.. Google it

Comment: Stephen the top answer will create a new id if the user reinstalls the app. I am looking for something that will hold constant.

Answer (score 0):

There was a flap a while ago and Apple removed the device UUID from the info available to third party developers. I don't think we are supposed to be able to get a unique device ID any more.

You might try the MAC address. If you search on "IOMACAddress" in Xcode you'll find an article that explains how to get the MAC address on Mac OS. I don't know if the same code will work on iOS or not, or if it will get your app rejected.

Comment: If you retrieve the MAC address post ios7 then you will find that you get the same value on all devices.