# How does paypal recognize the connected device?

Tags: paypal

What I would like to know is how does paypal recognize the connected device when you are making a payment, this is not really a coding question but I would like to know how it recognizes a device or what it uses to know if this device has connected before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know "what's the primary/first place that currently-logged-in/last-logged-in user information is stored, the answer is cookies/in-app property storage (for web/app respectively).

Beyond that, PayPal is not going to answer this question for you. Not because security through obscurity is a be-all, end-all answer, but they have no incentive to explicitly lay out exactly what they are doing in fraud prevention. Also, the answer isn't simple and isn't fixed: they use a variety of factors and how they do it evolves as technology (and policy) change. For example you can bet that they are cross-checking things like IP addresses, UDIDs, Android Device IDs, Apple Advertising IDs, and much much more to determine if the device you are currently using is a device that has done good -- or bad -- transactions before.

Comment: Hmm i underatand but my question was kind of from a programatic point of vue , as in when you are sending a request to paypal for a login or whatever is there something in the request that determines the device connected ? This question was for educational purposes only , I am just trying to get a global view on how that can be done

Answer (score 0):

i think the process is kind of divided in to 2 phases. on the server side, you have a api that register a client device. on the client side, be it browser or android or iphone app, your client send the identification information to the server.

- browser:
  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191840/how-web-servers-identify-a-client
- android app:
  [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)
- iphone app: [how to identify ios device uniquely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179799/how-to-identify-ios-device-uniquely)