# Create UUID for iPhone after iTunes/ ICloud Restore

Tags: ios, uniqueidentifier, udid

I was looking into ways of uniquely identifying and mapping user-device for our application and found this:

> [how to identify ios device uniquely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179799/how-to-identify-ios-device-uniquely)

We are creating our own UUID per device at backend and using that as a device specific id. The problem is when users restore with an iCloud or iTunes backup on their other phones all the device statistics and defaults are there in the new phone.
I need a way to reset everything if there is a new phone (give a new id to this new device for user).

I have already implemented this functionality: **If Model or Size of the phone is different from what it was seen first, I reset the defaults and consider it as a new phone but this fails if user restores everything to a new phone of same model and size.**

1. Is the method defined in the link above going to **create unique UDID for every new device**?
2. Is there any solution for the iTunes Restore issue from same model and size mentioned above?

Any help in this is highly appreciated.

Comment: identifierForVendor will give a different UUID for different physical phones, also if they have been restored from the cloud. However, it will also generate a different UUID when your app is removed and re-installed on the same phone. If that is not a problem for you, then identifierForVendor would be the answer.

Comment: Yes resetting IDs when app is removed is not a problem. I think that will surely fix the issue if identifierForVendor changes even if the app is restored from the backup from one phone to another.