# ios push notification and IDFA issue

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ads, udid

In my ios app I've used

```
 uuid = [[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier]
```

as udid for my push notification.

Today when I tried to publish my app, itunes asks me:

> This app uses the Advertising Identifier to (select all that apply):
>
> 1. Serve advertisements within the app.
> 2. Attribute this app installation to a previously served advertisement.
> 3. Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served
>      advertisement.

I use the uuid only for push notification. 
which of the 3 options should I choose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]
```

Is the better choice. You offer one single identifier for a device, even if the settings are reset.

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.[UIDevice#identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)

For more explanation, heres a good summary: [iOS6 UDID - What advantages does identifierForVendor have over identifierForAdvertising?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836225/ios6-udid-what-advantages-does-identifierforvendor-have-over-identifierforadve)

So, in case you do not use the advertisingIdentifier at all for advertising, you shouldn't make use of this => unfortunately, your question regarding the 3 approaches is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `IDFA` for advertising related purposes. It should not be used solely for uniquely identifying the device.

You can use `IDFA` for:

- frequency capping,
- conversion events,
- estimating the number of unique users,
- security and fraud detection,
- debugging

Consider using `identifierForVendor` class method of [`UIDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html).

If you want to know more about `IDFA`. I researched this topic and wrote an article about it here:

[**IDFA in iOS. What is the Advertising Identifier, how to use it, and why is it so important?**](http://stunningco.de/2014/04/13/what-is-the-advertising-identifier-idfa-on-ios-how-to-use-it-and-why-is-it-so-important/)