# Unique identifier in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Unique identifier for an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227590/unique-identifier-for-an-iphone-app)

Our  server database recognize user based on Device UDID, but now UDID is deprecated in iOS 5. I'm not able to use it. How can we identify the device?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **[OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID)**

> OpenUDID is a drop-in replacement for the deprecated uniqueIdentifier
>   property of the UIDevice class on iOS (a.k.a. UDID) and otherwise is
>   an industry-friendly equivalent for iOS and Android, and most recently
>   Windows C# and Silverlight (see links above).
>
> The agenda for this community driven project is to:
>
> Provide a reliable proxy and replacement for a universal unique device
>   identifier. That is, persistent and sufficiently unique, on a per
>   device basis. NOT use an obvious other sensitive unique identifier
>   (like the MAC address) to avoid further deprecation and to protect
>   device-level privacy concerns Enable the same OpenUDID to be accessed
>   by any app on the same device Supply open-source code to generate and
>   access the OpenUDID, for iOS and Android Incorporate, from the
>   beginning, a system that will enable user opt-out to match Apple’s
>   initial intent

Answer (score 0):

Use This....the easiest and most appropriate way to obtain a unique identifier is to use the mechanisms Apple explicitly provides for obtaining one`[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]`.

Comment: `uniqueIdentifier` was deprecated way back in iOS 5 and completely removed a bit later.