# How can I get the MCC and MNC on an iPhone

Tags: iphone

As per the subject - is there an API to get the MCC/MNC on iPhone OS 2.1 or above?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Added in iOS4

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *mcc = [carrier mobileCountryCode];
NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Don't forget to #import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h> and include the CoreTelephony Framework

Answer (score 1):

No, mobile network information is not available through the API.  If you're looking for a unique device ID, take a look at UIDevice's uniqueIdentifer method; if you're looking for the country the device is in, you need Location Services; if you want a good indication of the user's home region, take a look at NSLocale; for anything else, just ask the user.

Comment: Thanks for the response - sadly Location Services requires asking the user, in the sense that they get a popup asking if it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just get the [phone number of the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os) and parse it out for the country code.

Comment: The phone number is not available programmatically