# iphone sim number

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically get own phone number in iPhone OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

How do I get the phone number in iPhone?

Comment: Have a look at this SO question [programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

Comment: Just be aware that the method described there is highly unreliable.  If the user ported their number from a different carrier it will return incorrect results.  And there really is no better way.

Also be aware that Apple would probably reject your app from the store for using this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO, you can't... SDK does not help you. However, through CoreTelephony framework (4.x+) you can get info such as network code, network name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

interesting read: http://www.kuberan.me/2011/03/your-mobile-numbers-are-being-stolen-by-websites/