# Palm WebOS - How to get user's phone number?

Tags: webos, palm-pre

How do I get the user's phone number on Palm Pre's WebOS?

Thanks,

Comment: I received an answer here, http://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=792&p=2964#p2964, that says no.  Any better answers?  ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, the answer is that it is [not available for security reasons](http://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=792&p=2964#p2964).

We know the iPhone isn't secure, but [it allows it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os).  Everybody says the Blackberry is very secure and [it allows it too](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/Phone.html).

Disappointing...