# Is it possible to read the iPhone phone number out of the settings?

Tags: iphone, settings

I would like to pre-populate a UITextfield with the phone number of the current iPhone device. Can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it and I certainly hope not.  Imagine that I download an app and it automatically transmits my phone number to a remote server.

Actually it looks like it might be/have been possible: http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2008/11/15/snippet-phone-number/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but it's not going to be approved for App Store if you do it.

Answer (score 0):

hmm just found this post. The answer is that it can be done but we are not supposed to do it...

[Programmatically get own phone number in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

tnx for reading