# Get an iPad/iPhones unique information from your app?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How do you get the unique identifying information from an iPhone/iPad within an app?  For instance, I want my app to send support emails to my website for users who have problems and I need to uniquely identify the phone number/id of the device it is running on.  Is this possible, forbidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique identifier for the particular iPhone you're running on:

```
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

More info on [CFUUID](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's some discussion about getting the user's phone number here:

[Programmatically get own phone number in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)