# SBFormattedPhoneNumber issue in iOS4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the below code in my application which works perfectly in iPhoneOS 3.1.3 but not working in iOS 4.0. Any body affected by using this.

```
NSString *currentPhoneNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the SBFormattedPhoneNumber key/value data has been removed from the NSUserDefaults object as of 4.0.  No device number retrieval love; can't really say that the writing wasn't on the wall based upon [Dylan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128501/dylan) response to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os).

Comment: Many Thanks... i referred many sites. it's refused by Apple to get the users number by using SBFormattedPhoneNumber. And also the function not get the sim number directly instead by  user enter for any itunes activation etc..,   
 Regards
venkat