# NSUserDefaults SBFormattedPhoneNumber doesn't work on iPhone OS4

Tags: iphone

Does anybody know how to programmatically get my own phone number on iPhone OS4?
My app currently does it and works fine (iPhone OS 3.x).
But now, after upgrading my OS to 4 it stopped working.

Tks.

Comment: duplicate of [SBFormattedPhoneNumber issue in iOS4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108487/sbformattedphonenumber-issue-in-ios4-0)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forget to synchronise your NSUserDefaults.
do this :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```