# Find own phone number

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically get own phone number in iPhone OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

Hi, 
how i can get own phone number programmatically.

thanks in Advance

*Tom smith*

Comment: @Eiko, not really a duplicate because the latest SDK has prevent apps from getting the phone number. App will now have to ask the user for that information.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible anymore since iOS 4.  See [SBFormattedPhoneNumber issue in iOS4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108487/sbformattedphonenumber-issue-in-ios4-0) for additional information.  For privacy reason, you need to ask the user for the device phone number.