# How to get mobile number from iPhone programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios

How to get mobile number from iPhone programmatically?

I tried the code below but it's not working.

```
NSString *num = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"];
```

Please suggest me a right way.

Thanks.

Comment: [duplicate of this oft asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os) and/or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108487/sbformattedphonenumber-issue-in-ios4-0)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the mobile number programmatically from iPhone, atleast not if jailbroken.

Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os) for more info.