# SBFormattedPhoneNumber is not working

Tags: iphone

I am using below code to get current user's phone number:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"];
```

But I don't understand why this function would return null, please help me to understand.

Comment: It will not work in ios 4.x.x or above you can refers [this][1] answer.  

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108487

Comment: It will not work in ios 4.x.x or above you can refers [this][1] answer.  


[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108487

Answer (score 1):

That is for Jailbroken devices. You should not use these codes if you want your app to be uploaded to AppStore.

Comment: is it possible to access current user phone no.

Comment: @PrashantSh no, I believe they patched `SBFormattedPhoneNumber` in iOS 4. Just ask the user for a phone number inside the app, that is acceptable.

Comment: but is there any other way to find owner's phone no. without added this in  application?