# datatype of The shared defaults object returned by NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults, shared-objects

while going through the class reference file for `NSUserDefaults`, I notice that the return value for `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`is

> **The shared defaults object**

what is this object, what is its type? which methods we can call on this object?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an instance of `NSUserDefaults`.  You can call any of the instance methods that are defined for that class.  (e.g.  `stringForKey:`, `dictionaryForKey:`....)

Comment: I was making one test to get phone number :   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"] this returns an empty string.

Comment: How does the object/string with that key get there in the first place?

Comment: SBFormattedPhoneNumber is the key used to get phone number. As I am checking from other documents, this is no longer in Use after iOS 4.x.x. is there a standard apple documentation which list all the keys supported?

Comment: Ah...that must have been removed a long time ago (in iOS-time).  You should be able to do something like `NSLog(@"Defaults: %@", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys]);` to see what's available.

Comment: but they should have allow that right? like location service, they can just notify the user and ask if the user allows to give out his/her number.

Answer (score 0):

```c
+ (NSUserDefaults *)standardUserDefaults
```

It is just class method for returning singleton object of type NSUserDefaults. So, you can invoke all methods for this class.

From [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#standartUserDefaults)

> The defaults are initialized for the current user. Subsequent modifications to the standard search list remain in effect even when this method is invoked again—the search list is guaranteed to be standard only the first time this method is invoked. The shared instance is provided as a convenience—you can create custom instances using alloc along with initWithUser: or init.

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"] returns empty string. what are the possible ways I will get the phone number?

Comment: Answer for you question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108487/sbformattedphonenumber-issue-in-ios4-0